# React js onClick function in a map function is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, map-function

I got these array in React which I want to use for writing and iterating through a bunch of menuitems. Im setting the state in my hook to false as default and are using the functions toggleMyIdOne and toggleMyIdTwo to update the state.

```
const [myIdOneToggler, setMyIdOne] = useState(false);
const [myIdOneToggler, setMyIdTwo] = useState(false);

const toggleMyIdOne= () => {
    setMyIdOne(!myIdOneToggler);
}

const toggleMyIdTwo= () => {
    setMyIdTwo(!myIdTwoToggler);
}

function Menu() {
    const menuItems = [
        {
            id: "myIdOne",
            state: "myIdOneToggler",
            name: "toggleMyIdOne",
            setState: "setMyIdOne",
            label: "MyIdOne"
        },
        {
            id: "myIdTwo",
            state: "myIdTwoToggler",
            name: "toggleMyIdTwo",
            setState: "setMyIdTwo",
            label: "MyIdTwo"
        },
```

Further down Im returning this for updating the state of the checkbox once it is clicked.

```
{menuItems.map(item => (
    <div className="grid-item">
        <input onClick={item.name} type="checkbox" id={item.id} checked={item.state}/>
        <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.label}</label>
    </div>
```

This is supposed to call the **toggleMyIdOne** and **toggleMyIdTwo** function. It works fine and as expected when it is not in a map function but in the mapfunction it seems to be something wrong with the way I am declaring the function name.

Im getting this errormessage:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected `onClick` listener to be a
>   function, instead got a value of `string` type.

It is obvious that react wont recognize the string from my declared array with menuitems as a function but I cannot figure out how I shall declare this to get it to work. Or is it not possible to do like this to make the code more compact.

Comment: Have you tried passing the function reference directly and not as a string?

Comment: You got this error because name is a string and you passed it to onClick event.

Comment: You can post what you are trying to achieve maybe there will be workaround . But I don't think there is solution for passing functiono name as string

Comment: Yes I actually want to pass the function name as a string. Or somehway else where it is possible to use my declared array for looping throgh the items

Comment: @ZombieTfk yes it works directlty but i want to have different functions based on the array

Answer (score 1):

here you are passing a String to click props wich it should accept only functions!
to solve this u can do:

```
  {menuItems.map(item => (
    <div className="grid-item">
        <input onClick={()=>checkfunction(name)} type="checkbox" id={item.id} checked={item.state}/>
        <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.label}</label>
    </div>
```

and if u want to fire each hook

```
const checkfunction=name={
if(name==="toggleMyIdOne")
    setMyIdOne(!myIdOneToggler);
else
    setMyIdTwo(!myIdTwoToggler);
}
```